# How to create a global transaction in c# between Oracle DB and MQ

Tags: c#, database, oracle11g, ibm-mq

I need to create an integration flow to move MQ message in a db table.
I would like ensure that:

- there is just one reader in MQ at time
- if something goes wrong during the db insert, I must leave the message in the queue

Could you suggest an example code?

Comment: Are you speaking about the IBM MQ product or another MQ?

Comment: I'm speaking about IBM MQ product and using the library amqmdnet and amqmdxcs.

Comment: MQ has a Manged .NET client, could you use .NET transactions to coordinate with the DB?